# Concatenating packets from connection.recv() in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, byte

I am programming a file transfer protocol that will use this method:

- Client sends binary file in chunks of 1024 bytes
- Server will receive those chunks and concatenate them in an object
- When object size becomes 100 MB or greater, it will be written to disk (in a new thread).

I guess doing this method will reduce disk write overhead, which will eventually reduce sending time.

I need a method to concatenate the packets received by `connection.recv()` and put them in memory.

Part of my server code :

```
while downloadCounter<fileSize:
    filedata=client.connection.recv(chunckSize)
    downloadCounter=len(filedata)+downloadCounter
    dataBuffer.append(bfiledata)
    # save when data is 100 mb size 100000000 in binary..
    if(len(dataBuffer)>=100000000):
        tFILE=Thread(target=saveToDisk,)
        tFILE._args=(dataBuffer,file,)
        tFILE.start()
        dataBuffer=NULL
```

Comment: In what way is it not currently functioning as desired?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [socket module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv), `connection.recv()` returns a string. I would suggest adding these strings to a list, and writing out that list becomes very simple:

```
data_list = []
buffer_size = 0
total_size = 0

# assuming file_size, chunk_size and out_file are already defined

while total_size < file_size:

    file_data = client.connection.recv(chunk_size)

    data_list.append(file_data)

    data_length = len(file_data)
    total_size += data_length
    buffer_size += data_length

    if buffer_size >= 100000000:
        t_file = Thread(target=save_to_disk, args=(data_list, out_file))
        t_file.start()
        data_list = []
        buffer_size = 0

# Since you said your example code is just a part of your whole script, I'm
# assuming you have proper thread cleanup here. Also, don't forget to lock
# your file access since you could have multiple threads trying to write to
# it at the same time

# In your save_to_disk function, use this:
file.writelines(data_list)
```

I have a few notes about your code:

- You should give the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a read. Every language has a style that is more or less standard, and in Python, underscores are preferred over camelcase, and conditional clauses shouldn't have parentheses around them. Also, there should be spaces between operators and their operands, as well as around the equals sign in assignments.
- As I did in my example here, you can create a `Thread` and supply it's arguments together. If you find yourself manually accessing an attribute that has a leading underscore, you're probably doing something wrong. By Python convention, leading underscores indicate that that method or attribute could be changed at any time without notice and break your code in future releases. They are not intended to be part of the API, and you shouldn't rely on them.
- There is no `NULL` in Python. Perhaps you meant `None`?
- Python has a shortcut for `foo = foo + bar`: `foo += bar`. It's nice to use such shortcuts when available.
- Notice how I've rearranged the calculation of the buffer size. Since I'm keeping two running counters now, I don't have to check the size of the entire buffer after every packet received. Arithmetic operations and integer comparisons will always be faster than calculating list lengths, so try to arrange your code more like this to eliminate unnecessary calculations.

Comment: can i ask u ,do you think the method above will really speed up file transfer?

Comment: I don't think you're going to see any speed benefit from doing this. I tried something similar recently, and didn't see any benefit. File writing in Python is already buffered by default, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), and you're just implementing another buffer. Also, it obviously can't go any faster than your client can send data anyway. You should really profile it first, and spend your time optimizing the bottlenecks that your profiling reveals.